# How can I map multiple hostnames to localhost?

Tags: windows-7, hosts

I'm testing an application on my PC, this application connects to various servers so I need to mimic that on my box.

How can I map hostnames to 127.0.0.1?

`localhost` already refers to 127.0.0.1, but how could I add more such as `server-1` and `server-2` to 127.0.0.1?

I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: Use different port numbers  like localhost:1111 , localhost:2222

Comment: I want to use different hostnames not different ports

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just edit your **`hosts`** file and use that to point to 127.0.0.1 or the local IP address of your machine.

The file is normally in: **`/windows/system32/drivers/etc`**

eg - here's mine and I have been testing a few 'servers' as you can see:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    192.168.202.32  feng
    192.168.202.241 helpdesk
    192.168.202.241 wiki
    192.168.202.241 rs
    192.168.202.241 precurio    
    192.168.202.241 zendto
```

Comment: You can put multiple hostnames in a single address line.

Comment: True - I put them on separate lines as its quick and easy to comment them in and out as needed.

Comment: @Linker3000 Is there a way to access that host on a different PC that's connected to the same network via VPN? I connect to my work VPN and this would give access to my server on my home PC via IP or the server name `servername.org.com` and this works fine on a browser. I've added a new host under that file `127.0.01 test555.com`. On the server I can RDP to can access it on the browser with the provider name there but if I was to do it on my home PC, still connected to the VPN, it does not work. Is this possible?